# what is grpc trailers metadata used for?

Tags: grpc

I was looking through grpc documents and found out that on the server-side you are able to set metadata both in the form of `headers` and `trailers`.
Headers seem like the usual replacement for normal HTTP headers with key-value mapping. I don't see any needs for trailers anymore seems the header is serving somewhat a similar purpose or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trailers can be used for anything the server wishes to send to the client after processing the request.  Typically this should be used for information common to all methods a service provides, for example, data about the load created by the RPC for metrics purposes.

Comment: but using headers would be able to do the same thing right? are there any special purposes or is it just some naming or usage convenience

Comment: For streaming RPCs, load information can only be computed *after* streaming the results back to the client, so headers cannot be used in this case.

Comment: why can't it be used? is it because streaming must maintain its Header while stream is going on? i haven't been going to deep into streaming RPC

Comment: Headers can only be sent at the start of the RPC (before any data), and trailers are sent at the end (after all data).

Answer (score 8):

gRPC uses HTTP trailers for two purposes.

- it sends its final status (grpc-status) as a trailer header after the content has been sent.

  - When an application or runtime error occurs during an RPC a Status and Status-Message are delivered in Trailers.
  - For responses end-of-stream is indicated by the presence of the END_STREAM flag on the last received HEADERS frame that carries Trailers
- The second reason is to support streaming use cases. These use cases last much longer than normal HTTP requests. The HTTP trailer is used to give the post-processing result of the request or the response. For example, if there is an error during streaming data processing, you can send an error code using the trailer, which is not possible with the header before the message body.

Source [1](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md) [2](https://blog.cloudflare.com/road-to-grpc/)